# Trying to create sql procedure, getting errors with concat

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE selectContacts

BEGIN

SELECT master_id, CONCAT_WS(" ",l_name, f_name) AS display_name

FROM master_name

ORDER BY l_name, f_name;

END
```

The error:

```
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok 'BEGIN

SELECT master_id, CONCAT_WS(" ",l_name, f_name) AS display_name

FROM' at line 3

Unrecognized data type. (near " " at position 75)
Unrecognized data type. (near ")" at position 90)
```

The unrecognized data type is located in the bracket of `concat_ws`. I have no clue what's wrong with it as it was working 2 months ago.

Comment: So what has changed in your setup since 2 months ago? What is the schema of `master_name`?

Comment: There is not much point in using a stored procedure for this. A select or a view would be a lot more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create syntax not quite right maybe just a typo.

CREATE PROCEDURE selectContacts()

Comment: If it is a typo, then should be closed as off-topic (typo).

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thanks